# Segue : Pass struct values to another struct instead of separate arrays?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, struct, segue

I currently have a struct data source that is being referenced in a tableview controller.
I current have my segue setup so that the elements from Cheat get passed into a new array for each element on my new tableview controller.

My question is, is it better this way, or could i pass the Cheat values into a new struct so that i can reference the new struct object on my new tableview controller, as experience has taught me that using objects instead of arrays seems to make my life a lot easier lol

If so, how would i go about achieving this?

Here is my data source:

```
struct Game {
    var name : String
    var cheat : [Cheat]
}

struct Cheat {
    var name : String
    var code : String
    var desc : String
    var iscode : Bool
}

var gameData = [
    Game(name: "Game1", cheat:[Cheat( name:"Cheat1", code:"Code1", desc:"Desc1", iscode: true ),Cheat( name:"Cheat2", code:"Code2", desc:"Desc2", iscode: false )])]
```

Here is my main tableview controller:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class GameListController: UITableViewController {

    var gamesArray = gameData

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        gamesArray.sortInPlace { $0.name < $1.name }
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }

    override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return gamesArray.count
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell!
        cell.textLabel?.text = gamesArray[indexPath.row].name
        return cell
    }

    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        if let destViewController = segue.destinationViewController as? CheatListController {

            let indexPath : NSIndexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow!

            var game = gamesArray[indexPath.row]

            destViewController.cheatnameArray = game.cheats.map({ $0.name })
            destViewController.cheatcodeArray = game.cheats.map({ $0.code })
            destViewController.cheatdescArray = game.cheats.map({ $0.desc })
        }
    }

}
```

And finally my 2nd tableview controller:
(I know i have not setup my table yet, but you can see the arrays that receive my data.)

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class CheatListController: UITableViewController {

    var cheatnameArray = [String]()
    var cheatcodeArray = [String]()
    var cheatdescArray = [String]()
    var iscodeArray = Bool()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

}
```

Comment: If I was going to pass anything, I'd pass the `Game` that matched the selected row.  What I'd probably do instead is create an object to serve as the data model for the application and make it responsible for managing your `gamesArray` so that the view controllers weren't dependent on each other at all.

Comment: That makes perfect sense, but being fairly new to swift, how would one go about passing Game for selected row?

Comment: Create a `Game?` var in `CheatListController` and set it instead of the arrays.